# How can I find the width and height of a specific word within a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, width

I'm trying to replace a specific *class-less* word, not the entire string, with a form of the same height (or font-size) and width.  I want it to work even if I change the CSS.  Here is my code:

```
var magicWord = "abracadabra";

var width = $('#words').width();
var height = $('#words').height();

var x = width + "px"; 
var y = height + "px";


$('html').append("<form><input type='text' style='width: "+x+"; height: "+y+"; font-family: Courier;'></form>")
```

Here is my updated [fiddlicious](http://jsfiddle.net/TWKcZ/4/).  I figured it out myself using replace().  Anything more efficient will be awarded the coveted green check mark.

Comment: Perhaps I'm crazy, but your fiddle seems to already be doing exactly what you're asking for. If I'm misunderstanding, please clarify what you're looking for and how your current solution (the fiddle) doesn't accomplish that task.

Comment: No it's finding the dimensions of the whole string.  I want just the word "abracadabra" without putting it into a class or id.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Will post a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to have the DOM identifier for that word. you can change your like :-

```
<span id ="words">Here is a bunch of <span> abracadabra </span> </span>
```

and javascript as

```
var magicWord = "abracadabra";

var width = $('#words span').width();
var height = $('#words span').height();

var x = width + "px";  
var y = height + "px"


$('html').append("<form><input type='text' style='width: "+x+"; height: "+y+"; font-     
family: Courier;'></form>")
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to wrap it in its own element or do something more obtuse (generate a new element with just those contents (somewhere offscreen perhaps), calculate the size of that element, and then remove it). You might be able to make a rough calculation based on element line-height and the width of characters (in em units), but without knowing which characters are in use or using a monospace font-family, I can't imagine it will be very accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Html canvas has a text metrics ability.  You can get the text width like this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.font="14px Verdana";
var width = context.measureText("abracadabra").width;
```

You can also get the height, but it's more difficult because you have to use canvas to do linescans.

Comment: This is really brilliant, but I'm having difficulty getting it to function. width is returning as 59, which seems very small—even at 1em.

Comment: Yes it seems too small for me too

Comment: Setting context.font = "2em Courier" gets it closer. Then I multipled width by 1.5, and it's pretty darn close. Update the css and the context.font and it seems to stay pretty close. If you can update context.font to match the css, this might the cleanest approach.

Comment: Apologies!  I forgot to give you the code to define which font to use:  context.font="14px Verdana" or your font.